# params[...] comparison raises "undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass" error in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to check below:

```
if params[:hidval] > "0"
OR
if !params[:hidval] < "1"
```

But it gave me error below:

```
undefined method `>' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I check above conditions in ruby on rails?

Answer (score 11):

The error message says it all. Make sure, the param actually exists. You try to compare nothing (`NilClass`) with a number. (which is actually a string, that will be your next problem)

Probably correct would be:

```
if params[:hidval].present? && params[:hidval] > 0
 # Do something ...
end
```

Comment: Except for string conversion.

Comment: Is a param always a string?

Answer (score 7):

As of Ruby 2.3, you can use the Safe Navigation Operator `&.` to streamline this:

```
irb(main):028:0>   5 > 0
=> true
irb(main):029:0> nil > 0
NoMethodError: undefined method '>' for nil:NilClass
    from (irb):29
irb(main):030:0>   5 &.> 0
=> true
irb(main):031:0> nil &.> 0
=> nil
irb(main):032:0>   5 &.> 99
=> false
```

This will typically get you what you want (e.g. conditional branching) since `nil` is falsey. But keep that in mind if you *actually* depend on an exact `false` value.

`&.` means to only call the trailing method if the leading object is not null. It makes a lot more sense in a chained method call like:

```
user&.deactivate!
```

But, since the greater-than operator `>` is *actually a method* in Ruby, it works here as well.

Personally, I'm not convinced the painful aesthetics of `params[:hidval] &.> "0"` makes this worthwhile...but that's just a question of style.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
if params[:hidval].present?
  if params[:hidval].to_i > 0
    # Greater than 0 condition
  else
    # Less than equal to 0 condition
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-reading this question, I realize I missed the mark on my first answer. It side-stepped the problem without addressing it.

The real problem you saw this error is that you probably put `!` in the wrong place.

If you meant, `if it is not less than "1"`, then you should write:

```
if !( params[:hidval] < "1" )
```

This compares hidval and "1" and THEN negates the result.

What you posted:

```
if !params[:hidval] < "1"
```

...first negates hidval (usually resulting in `false`) and then compares `false` (or possibly `true`) to see if it is less than "1". Not only does comparing `false` to a string not make much sense, you'll actually get you this error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `<' for false:FalseClass)
```